# How to insert 2 graphs in one column on python

Tags: python, graph, grid, plotly, line

Now i am learning python. My first problem is "How to insert 2 graphs in one column on python". Please help me

My code is: Used plotly.

```
fig0.update_traces(mode='markers', marker_line_width=1, marker_size=5)
fig0.update_layout(title='Confirmed case by gender',yaxis_zeroline=False, xaxis_zeroline=False)
fig0.show()

fig1 = px.line(timegender, x='date', y='deceased', color='sex', markers = True)
fig1.update_traces(mode='markers', marker_line_width=1, marker_size=5)
fig1.update_layout(title='Deceased case by gender',yaxis_zeroline=False, xaxis_zeroline=False)
fig1.show()
```

Comment: two graphs one column?  it's difficult to interpret this - 1. an active dashboard i.e. **dash**  2. multiple traces on using same axis,  where columns are categories on xaxis i.e. multiple traces in one figure 3. multiple sets of axis i.e. sub-plots

Answer (score 0):

- you are clearly plotting COVID cases by sex.  Have sourced data to demonstrate this
- key for plotting is structuring data frame

  1. make *sex* a column that contains *male* or *female*
  2. make *measure* a columns that contains *cases* or *deaths*
- data is for multiple countries, so have filtered to just *USA* for plotting
- it's then simple to generate rows or columns of charts

```
import requests
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# fmt: off
# sex disaggregation data
dfsda = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://globalhealth5050.org/?_covid-data=datasettable&_extype=csv").text))
# case / death data
dfall = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
    requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv").text))
dfall["date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfall["date"])
dfcc = pd.read_html("https://www.iban.com/country-codes")[0]


# data prep - join three data sources
df = dfsda.merge(dfcc, left_on="Country code", right_on="Alpha-2 code").merge(
    dfall, left_on="Alpha-3 code", right_on="iso_code"
)

# calc split between male & female
df2 = (
    df.loc[:,['Cases (% female)', 'Deaths (% female)', 'Alpha-2 code', 'Alpha-3 code', 'location', 'date', 'total_cases', 'total_deaths']]
    .dropna()
    .assign(
        **{"Cases (% female)": lambda d: d["Cases (% female)"].str.strip("%").astype(float) / 100,
            "Deaths (% female)": lambda d: d["Deaths (% female)"].str.strip("%").astype(float) / 100,
            "cases_male": lambda d: d["total_cases"] * (1 - d["Cases (% female)"]),
            "cases_female": lambda d: d["total_cases"] * (d["Cases (% female)"]),
            "deaths_male": lambda d: d["total_deaths"] * (1 - d["Deaths (% female)"]),
            "deaths_female": lambda d: d["total_deaths"] * (d["Deaths (% female)"]),
        }
    )
)
# fmt: on

# structure for plotting
df3 = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        df2,
        i=["Alpha-3 code", "location", "date"],
        stubnames=["cases", "deaths"],
        j="sex",
        sep="_",
        suffix=r"\w+",
    )
    .loc[:, ["cases", "deaths"]]
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_4": "measure", 0: "value"})
)

# finally plot
px.line(
    df3.loc[df3["Alpha-3 code"].eq("USA")],
    x="date",
    y="value",
    color="sex",
    markers=True,
    facet_col="measure",
).update_yaxes(matches=None).show()
px.line(
    df3.loc[df3["Alpha-3 code"].eq("USA")],
    x="date",
    y="value",
    color="sex",
    markers=True,
    facet_row="measure",
).update_yaxes(matches=None).show()
```

[image]